Unable to install gem Nokogiri 1.7.1 on Ruby 2.3.1 | Mac M1 | Sonoma OS
I am trying to set up a legacy rails repo that runs on Ruby 2.3.1, on my Macbook (M1 Pro, Mac OS Sonoma). Upon bundle install, I get this error about Nokogiri 1.7.1. Have tried a bunch of suggestions online but nothing has worked so far. Any idea how to fix this?
Tried the following

xcode-select --install - Says that the installed command line tools are already up to date
gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1' --platform=ruby -- --use-system-libraries - Got the same error as above in the question
manually tried installing gem install nokogiri -v 1.7.1 --source 'https://rubygems.org/' but got the error:

xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
    ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;

